# Plotting Hidden Weights

Tags: theano

I've had an interest for neural networks for a while now and have just started following the deep learning tutorials. I have what I hope is a relatively straight forward question that I am hoping someone may answer.

In the multilayer perception tutorial, I am interested in seeing the state of the  network at different layers (something similar to what is seen in this paper: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/publications2/index.php/publications/show/247 ). For instance, I am able to write out the weights of the hidden layer using:

```
    W_open = open('mlp_w_pickle.pkl','w')
cPickle.dump(classifier.hiddenLayer.W.get_value(borrow=True), W_open, -1)
```

When I plot this using the utils.py tile plotting, I get the following pretty plot [edit: pretty plot rmoved as I dont have enough rep].

If I wanted to plot the weights at the logRegressionLayer, such that

```
cPickle.dump(classifier.logRegressionLayer.W.get_value(borrow=True), W_open, -1)
```

what would I actually have to do? The above doesn't seem to work - it returns a 2darray of shape (500,10). I understand that the 500 relates to the number of hidden units. The paragraph on the Miscellaneous page:

> Plotting the weights is a bit more tricky. We have n_hidden hidden
>   units, each of them corresponding to a column of the weight matrix. A
>   column has the same shape as the visible, where the weight
>   corresponding to the connection with visible unit j is at position j.
>   Therefore, if we reshape every such column, using numpy.reshape, we
>   get a filter image that tells us how this hidden unit is influenced by
>   the input image.

confuses me alittle. I am unsure exactly how I would string it together.

Thanks to all - sorry if the question is confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could plot them just the like the weights in the first layer but they will not necessarily make much sense.

Consider the weights in the first layer of a neural network. If the inputs have size 784 (e.g. MNIST images) and there are 2000 hidden units in the first layer then the first layer weights are a matrix of size 784x2000 (or maybe the transpose depending on how it's implemented). Those weights can be plotted as either 784 patches of size 2000 or, more usually, 2000 patches of size 784. In this latter case each patch can be plotted as a 28x28 image which directly ties back to the original inputs and thus is interpretable.

For you higher level regression layer, you could plot 10 tiles, each of size 500 (e.g. patches of size 22x23 with some padding to make it rectangular), or 500 patches of size 10. Either might illustrate some patterns that are being found but it may be difficult to tie those patterns back to the original inputs.

Comment: Thanks alot for that. It does seem to have cleared up some of my confusion. The initial weights I were plotting were for the LogRegression class (the first tutorial) and looking at the weights you could see the numerals clear as day. I was expecting something similar at the higher levels as well.